# Django modify model instance from HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-models

I want to know if it is possible to directly modify and save a model instance in the HTML Template and not via a view and extra URL.

My user has a Boolean Property, I want to display it as a toggle button on the website and the user should be able to toggle it on or off without leaving the website or reloading it.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    autoplay_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

Is this possible without an extra view or form?
 
Basically I just need to set

```
request.user.autoplay_enabled = False (or True)
```

and then **`save()`** it

If I can't modify the object directly in the HTML template is it at least possible to just execute a function I have defined somewhere in my Python code, without having the need to create a new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't make any sense at all. HTML is just sent to the browser for display. You can't do *anything* "from HTML" without making some kind of request to the server, and the server won't do anything unless that request is received by some code - eg a view connected to a URL.

If you want something to happen without refreshing the page, you need to use Ajax. You can use a simple Ajax POST to a view that toggles the value and saves it - it only needs a dozen lines of code between front and back end.

Comment: I was hoping to write it directly into the HTML Template only, like {{ % user.autoplay_enabled=True % }} or {{ % call_to_function % }}. Thanks for your answer though. Now I know that I still need a custom URL and a view.